# File sorting using automation

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a process where I need to check all the files in the shared location. But before that, I need to sort all the files based on the Name. But, I don't know how to check if the file present in the location is already sorted or not.

[image]

I'm attaching images of the control identifiers to access the elements.
[image]

I have the access to the element but I don't know how to keep track of the element if it has been clicked before or not.

I'm using pywinauto library to automate the process.

Any help in regard to this problem is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil
```

#add the files diectory for path

```
path = '/path/to/directory'

list_ = os.listdir(path)

for file_ in list_: 
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file_)

    ext = ext[1:]

    if ext == '': 
        continue

    if os.path.exists(path+'/'+ext): 
        shutil.move(path+'/'+file_, path+'/'+ext+'/'+file_)
    else: 
        os.makedirs(path+'/'+ext) 
        shutil.move(path+'/'+file_, path+'/'+ext+'/'+file_)
```

Comment: Windows uses backslash as a path separator. For checking already created files it's better to use standard Python libraries, I agree here. Maybe some files are created by the GUI app, that's why pywinauto is used (maybe).